# Analyse call tree for R functions call in scripts

Tags: r

I am looking for a way to programmatically analyse (and manipulate) the call tree of function calls that I have in R scripts. I learnt that in the pryr package, there is a function pryr::ast() which returns the hierarchical tree structure of the call. I want something similar, but as I mentioned it needs to work on string input:

As an example, consider the content of the following example file **input.R** that is on my harddrive:

```
mean(sqrt(1:10 - 1), na.rm = T, trim = 0.1)
```

The task is to read **input.R** into R and then, essentially, walk over the script and collect the nested function calls in some form of a list, e.g. pryr prints this:

```
\- ()
 \- `mean
 \- ()
   \- `sqrt
   \- ()
     \- `-
     \- ()
       \- `:
       \-  1
       \-  10
     \-  1
  \- `T
  \-  0.1
```

Is there some elegant way to do this or do I have to ues some form of regex to identify the calls?

Comment: What you’re looking at is a *parse tree*, not a call tree. A call tree is something different (although related). Also, since you evidently know about pryr, what exactly is the question about?

Comment: Actually, I have to admit that even Hadley’s “Advanced R” tutorial gets this wrong and uses the term “call tree”. And even my comment was somewhat wrong: the general term is “syntax tree”, of which “parse tree” is largely a synonym, but this usage sounds weird outside the context of a parser (to illustrate this, the result of `call('+', quote(a), 1)` is a *syntax tree* but since it wasn’t *parsed* – rather, it was constructed from function calls – the term “parse tree” would be weird here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

- use `parse(text = ...)` to convert your string into an expression
- use `call_tree()` from the package `pryr` to build the call tree
- use `capture.output` to grab the results from `stdout` into a list

For example:

```
library(pryr)
f <- "mean(sqrt(1:10 - 1), na.rm = T, trim = 0.1)"
x <- capture.output(call_tree(parse(text=f)))
```

Your result is a character vector (i.e. a list)

```
x
 [1] "\\- ()"          "  \\- `mean"     "  \\- ()"        "    \\- `sqrt"   "    \\- ()"     
 [6] "      \\- `-"    "      \\- ()"    "        \\- `:"  "        \\-  1"  "        \\-  10"
[11] "      \\-  1"    "  \\- `T"        "  \\-  0.1 "    

str(x)
 chr [1:13] "\\- ()" "  \\- `mean" "  \\- ()" "    \\- `sqrt" "    \\- ()" ...

cat(x, sep="\n")
\- ()
  \- `mean
  \- ()
    \- `sqrt
    \- ()
      \- `-
      \- ()
        \- `:
        \-  1
        \-  10
      \-  1
  \- `T
  \-  0.1
```

Comment: @KonradRudolph Maybe, but it wasn't obvious to me from the question.  It certainly wasn't obvious to me how to get this result using a `string` as input.  The examples in `ast()` only demonstrate how to do this with expressions, not strings.

Comment: pryr exists mainly (exclusively?) as a complement to [a tutorial about R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/). And there, parsing is explained directly before operations on the AST.

Comment: This was useful to me. I wasn't aware of call_tree/capture.output, but the output is what I was looking for.

Comment: I'm interested in this too, but I would rather work with a nested list or `igraph` object than a printout of text. Not sure I'd do a good job parsing it.